# How to explicitly send request.auth.uid in Firestore?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I use a Node.js backend to make some validation before creating documents in Firestore. That being said, if all checks pass, I use `firebase-admin` to create documents on behalf of some users.

In Firestore I setup some security rules like:

```
...
    match /some_collection {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == 'some_specific_uid';
    }
...
```

Normally, `request.auth.uid` is populated by `Firebase.auth()` when a user logs in on the front-end, which is not my case.

In fact this is what I use:

```js
const firebase_admin = require('firebase-admin');

/**
* SOME BUSINESS VALIDATIONS HERE
*/
// ...

// IF ALL VALIDATIONS PASS
// Do some stuff in firebase

firebase_admin.initializeApp(process.env.CREDENTIALS);

let db = firebase_admin.firestore();

// HOW TO SEND uid along with this:
db.collection('some_collection').doc('my_doc').update({'key': 'value'})
```

So, how to explicitly send UID (or any data for that matter) to Firestore that can be catchable using `request.auth.uid` (or `request.data.uid`) from security rules?

Comment: How did you resolve this in the end. What I am thinking is that I'll pass the uid from the front end to the backend, then set the uid in a normal field within the collection. Then change the firestore rule to match against that field instead of request.auth.uid. No idea if that's good practice or not.

Comment: Actualy seems like that is the correct approach as per the Data validation section here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the Firebase Admin SDK, all access to Firestore happens with administrative credentials, which bypass the security rules that you configured. There is no way to change this behavior of the Admin SDK for Firestore, soyou must make sure the data your code writes through the Admin SDK meets all business rules of your app.

The only other thing I can think of is using the [Node.js SDK for clients](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node), which allows you to sign in with Firebase Authentication as other clients do.

Comment: Users are logged "the classic way" from the front-end using `firebase.auth()`. So is there a way I can kinda RE-log a user using the `Node.js SDK for clients`?